# Can we can get resolved value directly instead of Promise { <pending> } (similar to async-await but only using promises)

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, es6-promise

I want to create a function foo returning 'success' after 2 seconds using only promises.(similar to async-await)

```
function foo() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve('success');
        }, 2000);
    })
}

foo().then(function (value) {
    console.log(value);
})

//Can we do something like this? 
// let value = foo();
// console.log(value)
```

Comment: No, we cannot (without using `let value = await foo()`).

Comment: Yes @Bergi 
But I want the resolved value to be returned value of foo function without using await

Comment: As I just said, this is impossible. You cannot immediately get a value that will be available in the future only.